# Binary files corrupted during segmented download

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, for-loop, urllib

So Im trying to code a really simple Internet Download Manager Spoof with Python 2.7

It is supposed to query a files HTTP header, get the byte range and spread the download among a no.of threads(I hard-coded 2 for simplicity) according to the byte range and later join the file parts together again.

The script manages to download csv files and text files easily without the file losing integrity. The MD5 checksum remains the same

The problem is that for files that have a little complexity e.g bin files, zip files, video files and music files, the integrity is lost for some reason. I think the order of the bytes is being jumbled up.

Example:

1. [mp3 downloaded through Chrome](http://picosong.com/bpiU/)
2. [mp3 downloaded through my script with 2 threads](http://picosong.com/bpMF)

Python source:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import threading
import urllib
import urllib2

import time

threads = []
parts = {}

# url to open
url = "http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/india-national-anthem.mp3"
u = urllib.urlopen(url)

# define file
file_name = "test.mp3"
f = open(file_name, 'wb')


# open url and get header info
def get_file_size(url):
    stream_size =  u.info()['Content-Length']
    file_size = stream_size
    return file_size

start = 0
#get stream size
end = get_file_size(url)
# specify block size
block_sz = 512

#algo to divide work among 2 threads
def calculate_no_of_bytes_for_thread1():
    full_stream_size = end
    first_thread = {'start':0, 'end':(int(full_stream_size)/2)}
    print(first_thread)
    return first_thread

#algo to divide work among 2 threads
def calculate_no_of_bytes_for_thread2():
    full_stream_size = end
    second_thread= {'start':int(full_stream_size)/2,'end': int(full_stream_size)}
    print(second_thread)
    return second_thread



# download function
def download_thread(url ,id,start,end):
    current_size = int(float(start)/1024)
    total_size = int(float(end)/1024)
    print ("Start at_"+str(current_size) + "Ends at_" + str(total_size))

    # specify request range and init stream
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (start, end)

    while True:
        buffer = u.read(block_sz)
        if not buffer:
            break
        start += len(buffer)
        f.write(buffer)
        thread_id = id
        status =  "Thread ID_" +str(thread_id) + "Downloaded_" + str(int(start/1024)) + "Total_" +str(total_size)
        print (status)

#starts 2 threads
def start_threads():
    for i in range(2):
        #if first loop, start thread 1
        if(i==0):
            start = calculate_no_of_bytes_for_thread1().get('start')
            end = calculate_no_of_bytes_for_thread1().get('end')
            print("Thread 1 started")
            t = threading.Thread(target=download_thread, args=(url,i,start,end))
            t.start()
            threads.append( t)
        #if second loop, start thread 2
        if(i==1):
            start = calculate_no_of_bytes_for_thread2().get('start')
            end = calculate_no_of_bytes_for_thread2().get('end')
            print("Thread 2 started")
            t = threading.Thread(target=download_thread, args=(url,i,start,end))
            t.start()
            threads.append( t)

    # Join threads back (order doesn't matter, you just want them all)
    for i in threads:
       i.join()

    # Sort parts and you're done
    # result = ''
    # for i in range(2):
    #     result += parts[i*block_sz]

#start benchmarking
start_time = time.clock()

start_threads()

print ("Finito!")

end_time = time.clock()
benchmark = str(end_time - start_time)
print ("Download took_" +benchmark)

f.close()
```

So after some insight from Mark, (Thank you) I got the script working and it downloads the file perfectly. I learnt that every single byte matters! So here is the **WORKING CODE**:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import threading
import time

f = open("newfile.zip", "wb")
url = "http://greenbookhymns.s3.amazonaws.com/245to257.zip"
parts = {}
threads = []

#gets file size
d = urllib.urlopen(url)
file_size = d.info()['Content-Length']
print ("File Size = " + str(file_size))

#get thread_no
thread_no = int(file_size) / 1000000

#urllib2 range download function
def download(thread_no,start_point, end_point):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (start_point, end_point)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    parts[thread_no] = f.read()

#launch threads targeting download function
def thread_launcher(thread_no):
    for i in range(thread_no):
        if i == 0:
            t = threading.Thread(target=download, args=(i,0,1000000,))
            t.start()
            threads.append( t)
            print "iteration 0starting_point0ending_point1000000"
        elif i > 0:
            start_point = (i*1000000)+1
            end_point = (i*1000000)+1000000
            t = threading.Thread(target=download, args=(i,start_point,end_point,))
            t.start()
            threads.append( t)
            print "iteration" + str(i) + "starting_point" + str(start_point) + "end_point" + str(end_point)

        last_file_part_start_point = (thread_no * 1000000) +1
        remaining_bytes= int(file_size) - int(thread_no*1000000)
        print str(remaining_bytes)
        last_file_part_end_point = (thread_no*1000000) + remaining_bytes
        print "iteration" + str(thread_no) + "starting_point" + str(last_file_part_start_point) + "end_point" + str(last_file_part_end_point)
        t = threading.Thread(target=download, args=(thread_no,(last_file_part_start_point), last_file_part_end_point,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

thread_launcher(thread_no)

# Join threads back (order doesn't matter, you just want them all)
for i in threads:
    i.join()

# Sort parts and you're done
result = ''
for i in range(thread_no+1):
    result += parts[i]

f.write(result)

f.close()

exit()
```

Comment: I suggest use `requests` and `stream=True`.

Comment: I tried requests and stream=True, nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your download thread function writes data to file `f` as it is received. You have two threads running in parallel so it is jumbling the received data into the file.

Comment: OMG you again? So what should I do? Make the threads save the files as different files and merge the two files when finished?

Comment: @KenOkech, concatenate the data into a separate buffer in each thread, then join them together after the threads finish like in your `# Sort parts...` comment.  Good luck!